# Проблема с SELECT

Tags: sql

````
SET @НомерАбонемента = -- задайте номер абонемента читателя

-- Запрос по заданному номеру абонемента
SELECT
    Читатель.НомерАбонемента,
    Читатель.ФИО AS 'ФИО читателя',
    ЭкземплярИздания.ИнвентарныйНомер AS 'Инвентарный номер',
    ПечатноеИздание.НазваниеИздания AS 'Название издания',
    ЭкземплярИздания.ДатаПоступления AS 'Дата поступления',
    АбонементыИздания.ДатаВыдачи AS 'Дата выдачи',
    АбонементыИздания.ДатаВозвратаПлановая AS 'Плановая дата возврата',
    АбонементыИздания.ДатаВозвратаФактическая AS 'Фактическая дата возврата'
FROM
    Читатель
JOIN
    АбонементыИздания ON Читатель.НомерАбонемента = АбонементыИздания.НомерАбонемента
JOIN
    ЭкземплярИздания ON АбонементыИздания.ИнвентарныйНомер = ЭкземплярИздания.ИнвентарныйНомер
JOIN
    ПечатноеИздание ON ЭкземплярИздания.ББК = ПечатноеИздание.ББК
WHERE
    Читатель.НомерАбонемента = @НомерАбонемента
    AND АбонементыИздания.ДатаВозвратаФактическая < GETDATE();```



**Выдает ошибку**
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "SELECT".
````

Comment: Возможно, нужен разделитель между командами SET и SELECT? 
SET @НомерАбонемента = -- задайте номер абонемента читателя; у SET еще возможно нужно тип задать. Укажите диалект SQL - где пишете этот код?

Comment: SQL Server не будет запрашивать данные при их отсутствии - `SET` выполняет присвоение явно прописанного в коде значения, которого в показанном коде нет. Вот и получается `SET @НомерАбонемента = SELECT ...` - явно синтаксически ошибочная конструкция.